# Win Server 2016 install fails on HP Proliant ML350p G8 with error “We couldn’t create a new partition or locate an existing one see setup log files”

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, hp-proliant

I am having an issue with installing Windows Server 2016 on my Proliant ML350p G8. Every time I try to install to a drive, I get this: “We couldn’t create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information, see the setup log files”. The setup logs are below:
`[0x0606cc] IBS CreatePartition: Requested partition looks invalid (offset = [0], size = [240056360960]) [0x060cc] IBS ApplyDiskOperationUsingService: Failed to correctly apply disk operation of type [0x7]; hr = 0x80004005 [0x060492] IBS PerformDiskOperation:DIsk operation of type [7] failed; hr = 0x80004005`

As for drives I have

6x 600GB 10k RPM HDDs - RAID array (3.6tb)
4x 1TB 10k RPM HDDs - RAID array (4tb)
1x 1TB 7200 RPM HDD - Standalone connected to motherboard
1x 250gb SSD - Standalone connected to motherboard

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like what's happening is that Windows is trying to create a partition spanning the entire 250G SSD, rather than creating a partition table and then specifying that the OS partition use the entire rest of the disk. I have no idea why it would do this. What I would do in your position is grab a copy of some Linux distribution and boot to that, then use that to fdisk the SSD. Create a single partition for the entire SSD, I'd suggest not GPT though I don't think it really matters. Then retry your Windows install.

One other thing to check is whether you may have inadvertently connected both the SSD and the 1TB 7200RPM disk to the same SATA channel. If you're using a SATA connected (type B) SSD on the motherboard, that will sit on the same SATA channel as one of the SATA connectors. This won't be the case for NVMe SSDs, which talk PCIe directly; though some of those will claim PCIe vias without notice, possibly making add-on cards behave strangely.